# Input assigned incorrectly

Tags: python

```
def roman_value(roman):

    roman_values = (('I',1), ('IV',4), ('V',5), ('IX',9),('X',10),('XL',40),('L',50),('XC',90),('C',100),
                    ('CD', 400), ('D', 500), ('CM', 900), ('M',1000))

    romanSymbol = input("enter roman symbols < 3999: ")

    total=0

    for symbol,value in reversed(roman_values):
        while roman.startswith(symbol):
            total += value
            roman = roman[len(symbol):]
    return total

if __name__=='__main__':
    for value in "MCMXC", "MMVIII", "MDCLXVI", "":
        print('%s = %i' % (value, roman_value(value)))

roman_value()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi I am trying to get the input to accept the input and then it can display the output which should be an integer, although I have found that I might need to add some more roman symbols into the list, for now I am not sure why it does not want to accept an input, I am missing something here...

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to do here. What's the point of your program? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but your input `romanSymbol` is never used.

Comment: User inputs roman numerals and then I am trying to convert it to an integer, just cant get this one right

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually wanting something like this:

```
def roman_value():

    roman_values = (('I',1), ('IV',4), ('V',5), ('IX',9),('X',10),('XL',40),('L',50),('XC',90),('C',100),
                    ('CD', 400), ('D', 500), ('CM', 900), ('M',1000))

    romanSymbol = input("enter roman symbols < 3999: ")
    roman = romanSymbol

    total=0

    for symbol,value in reversed(roman_values):
        while roman.startswith(symbol):
            total += value
            roman = roman[len(symbol):]

    print('%s = %i' % (romanSymbol, total))

roman_value()
```

Comment: That is correct, it works, I could not identify what I was missing, thank you, still got some testing to do, with other roman symbols, if I get stuck I get back...